# Injecting $mdDialog into factory creates circular dependency

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

[image]I started to include angular-material into angular 1.5v project. I am also using ionic-latest that includes ng-animate and ng-sanitize files bundled. Iam getting below error when I inject $mdDialog service into factories but it works fine when I inject $mdDialog into controllers. What could be the cause How do I get around this?

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $http <- $templateRequest <- $$animateQueue <- $animate <- $$interimElement <- $mdDialog <- alumDialogFactory <- HttpHandler <- $http <- $templateFactory <- $view <- $state

dialog.factory.js
------------------------
angular
.module('app.factory.Dialog')
.factory('DialogFactory', ['$mdDialog', function($mdDialog) {
    return {
        alert: function($mdDialog, title, msg) {
            $mdDialog.show(
                $mdDialog.alert()
                .parent(angular.element(document.querySelector('#popupContainer')))
                .clickOutsideToClose(false)
                .title(title)
                .textContent(msg)
                .ariaLabel(title)
                .ok('OK')
                .targetEvent()
            );
        }, 
}]);
```

Comment: It solely depends on where the service is being used. As always, circular dependencies are resolved with $injector.get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can $inject any dependency dynamically:

```
.factory('DialogFactory', ['$injector', function($injector) {
    return {
        alert: function(title, msg) {
            var $mdDialog = $injector.get('$mdDialog');
            ...
        }
```

Comment: There's no reason for  $injector.get('$mdDialog') to be inside alert. It can be called once outside the method.